# $\arccos(1/2)$ products

Tags: trigonometry

I'm finding points of intersection between two functions, $y = \tan(x)$ and $y = 2\sin(x)$, which are bound between $-\pi/3$ and $\pi/3$.

Solving for the intersections points, I end up performing $x = \arccos\left(\frac12\right)$

I know this produces: $x = \pi/3$, *but should it rather produce $x = \pm\pi/3$ ?*

This seems to make sense as visually the two functions intersect at both $-\pi/3$ and $\pi/3$, but I want to verify if this is correct.

I'm usually on Stack Overflow. Let me know if any notation here is wrong. Additional apologies if this question is very low level, I haven't worked with trig in a while.

Comment: WolframAlpha offers  solutions [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve+y+%3D+tan%28x%29+and+y+%3D+2sin%28x%29+for+x). To solve it manually, I think you would need to expand $2\sin{x}$ with the law of cosines and then see which trig functions cancels if they do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that\begin{align}\tan(x)=2\sin(x)&\iff\frac{\sin(x)}{\cos(x)}=2\sin(x)\\&\iff\sin(x)=0\vee\cos(x)=\frac12.\end{align}And$$\cos(x)=\frac12\iff x=\frac\pi3+2n\pi\vee x=-\frac\pi3+2n\pi,$$with $n\in\Bbb Z$.

In particular, although $\arccos\left(\frac12\right)\left(=\frac\pi3\right)$ is indeed a solution of the equation $\cos(x)=\frac12$, it is not the only one.

Comment: Thanks for your time, great answer!

Comment: I'm glad I could help.

Answer (score 3):

Let $ x\in[-\frac{\pi}{3},\frac{\pi}{3}] $.

$$\tan(x)=2\sin(x) \iff$$

$$\sin(x)(1-2\cos(x))=0\iff$$

$$\cos(x)=\frac 12 =\cos(\frac{\pi}{3})\iff $$

$$x=\pm \frac{\pi}{3}+2k\pi$$

but, if $ k\ne 0$, then $ x $ is out of the domain $ [-\frac{\pi}{3},\frac{\pi}{3}]$.
So, $ k=0 $ and$$x=\pm \frac{\pi}{3}$$

Comment: Thanks! I like the layout of this answer. I'd mark this right, but Jose answered first with a similar answer. Thanks for your time

Comment: @lime If it could help, that is enough for me.

Answer (score 2):

The Cosine function is positive is Quadrants I and IV. Therefore, given $\cos(x)=\dfrac{1}{2}$, $x=\dfrac{\pi}{3}$ is the solution from Quadrant I and $x=-\dfrac{\pi}{3}$ (or $x=\dfrac{5\pi}{3}$) is the solution from Quadrant IV.

In high school, I remembered this using the acronym "[All Students Take Calculus](https://sites.google.com/site/fideljrsaenz/home/pre-calculus/weekending11102016)".

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'll make sure to write that down!